# How to implement searchFilter in ListView having Alphabet-indexed Section Headers

Tags: android, android-listview, filter

I have to implement Filter in  ListView having Alphabetical SectionHeader .[ListView having Alphabetic Section Header](http://eshyu.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/cursoradapter-with-alphabet-indexed-section-headers/)

I used the example from above link to create my ListView. How to implement Search Filter in this ListView. I need a Layout like the below[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
For this to implement you need a TextWatcher for the edittext in which user will type when user will type something you create a Arraylist that will be updated with the items and then notify the Listview


search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   Boolean called =false;
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    coffeeshopsearch=new ArrayList<CoffeeShopBean>();
    for (int i = 0; i < coffeeShop.size(); i++) {
     if(coffeeShop.get(i).name1.toLowerCase().contains(String.valueOf(s).toLowerCase()))
     {
      coffeeshopsearch.add(coffeeShop.get(i));
     }
    }
    if(coffeeshopsearch.size()>0)
    {
     lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     adapter.add(coffeeshopsearch);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else
    {
     if(!called)
     {
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Items Found!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      called=true;
     }
     lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
   }
```

Comment: I used curosr adapter